# Question about calculating the gradient of a composite function

Tags: calculus

I am new to calculus and was asked to answer the following question. I have added my answer, although I am not sure at all whether it is correct. Any feedback would be amazing! Thanks in advance

$\mathbf {r} = (x,y)=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$

r = $\left\lVert r\right\rVert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Let's assume that $\mathbf{r} \neq0$

We now define $f(x,y)=r^m$

What is the right expression for $\nabla{}f$?

1. $mr^{m-1}\mathbf{r}$
2. $mr^{m-2}\mathbf{r}$
3. $mr^{m-1}$
4. $mr^{0.5m-1}\mathbf{r}$

My reasoning was that it should be number 1:

the derivative of $f$ according to $x$ comes out as $mr^{m-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$, while the derivative of $f$ according to $y$ comes out as $mr^{m-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\left\lVert r\right\rVert=1$, and therefore this is equal to $mr^{m-1}\mathbf{r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in what you have written suggests that $\|r\|=1$. What you have shown is that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = mr^{m-1} \frac{x}{r}=mr^{m-2} x$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = mr^{m-1} \frac{y}{r}=mr^{m-2} y.$$
So, 
$$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \textbf{i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \textbf{j} = \cdots$$